# How to move caret to a specific position after performing code fix

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible to move caret to a specific position after performing codefix?

Imagine following scenario:
- near the beginning of the source code I am editing, there is an error that my code analyzer detects and highlights with red squiggles
- I am editing the file so the highlighted error is out of the displayed scope
- using the mouse wheel, I get to the aforementioned error
- after hovering the squiggles the error popup appears with the suggested code fix
- after performing it, view of the editor returns back to the caret position
- I cannot immediately see result of the code fix

The solution would be to move caret position to the place where code fix took place. However I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: I doubt this is possible since the caret is an IDE feature and diagnostics are supposed to be IDE agnostic -- it might just as well be a console project or a PCL. I couldn't find an existing issue on the repo page so you could always propose it yourself: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues

Comment: I don't quite agree - can't seem to find a reason why diagnostics should be IDE agnostic (have you meant code analysis in general? If so, I agree with you). On the contrary, you cannot write code analyzer for other IDE than VS.

I am not sure if this is something Roslyn team should address. From my point of view, it is more a generic Visual Studio extension thing (on a side note, even the "native" code fixes behave the same way). I might not have used suitable set of tags for my question, though.

Comment: Well, for starters the diagnostics can be perfectly used in console applications or class libraries. Maybe you could do something with that Vsix project but I have no experience in that area.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a vsix extension this should get you close at least.

```
IVsTextManager textManager = (IVsTextManager)GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
IVsTextView textView = null;
textManager.GetActiveView(1, null, out textView);
IComponentModel componentModel =(IComponentModel)GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.IWpfTextView textView =  componentModel.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>().GetWpfTextView(textView);

textView.Caret.MoveTo(/*lots of overrides*/);
```